# waterline.js how to associate a model that can have sub models of the same model itself?

Tags: javascript, sails.js, waterline

Is there a way to associate a model that can have sub models of itself?

In this example there's a model of 'component' that might have sub components of the same type:

```
{
identity: 'component',
connection: 'default',
attributes: {
    id: {
        type: 'string',
        unique: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        required: true
    },
    name: 'string',

    from_device: {
        model: 'device',
        via: 'id'
    },

    dataItems: {
        collection: 'dataitem'
    },

    subComponents:{
        collection: 'component',
        via: 'id',
        // through: 'componentsubcomponent'
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ofc. That works nested comment eg. on Facebook.

Example:

```
// models/Comment.js
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    parent: {
      model: "comment"
    },
    children: {
      collection: 'comment',
      via: 'parent'
    },
    content: {
      type: "text",
      required: true
    },
    author: {
      model: "user",
      required: true
    }
  }
};
```